# Files.lines method removes line ending character

Tags: java, nio

I observed that the below code removes the line ending character(^M DOS/Windows line-ending character)

```
 Files.lines(Paths.get("filePath/file.txt"))
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```

The javadoc doesn't say that it will remove it, was it by design or am I missing something here?

What if I have to preserve the original line ending character.

Comment: It was by design (do `System.out::println`). Otherwise one would have to handle to line endings like CR, LF, CR+LF, none at the end, NEL.

Comment: But that's the line delimiter... Right? If you need it, you can just assume there's one after each line. On the contrary, I think that the current implementation is more intuitive.

Comment: In that case I should just assume that, rather its new learning for me :)

Comment: What if I have to preserve the original line ending character.

Answer (score 0):

You are yourself removing it. As you are using lines method , it will pick each line one by one and pass it as a stream and then you are printing it using System.out.print instead of System.out.println and hence no new line printed from the stream.

Hope that helps. :)

--EDIT--

As mentioned in the comments, for .lines() line ending is a delimeter and delimeter is never returned in the tokens. You may assume every line except last line to have line ending at end.

Or you can update your code as below:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("filePath/file.txt")).map(p->p+"\n")
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```

But then in this case, it will add line ending even in the last line as well.

Comment: System.out.print is for illustrative purpose, if I redirect output to another file then end char is gone.

Comment: That is how lines is picking up each line, for that line ending is a delimeter and delimeter is never returned in tokens. You may assume every line except the last line to have line ending at the end